# How can I create a document-based application that cannot create a new document?

Tags: cocoa, nsdocument

I have a document-based application that is designed to process existing documents, not to create new documents.

How do I prevent the application from creating a new, blank document when launched by opening it from the Finder?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is an NSApplication delegate protocol method you can implement.

```
 - (BOOL)applicationShouldOpenUntitledFile:(NSApplication *)sender {
    return NO;
}
```

Here's the [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSApplicationDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008592-CH1-SW39)

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what you are specifically doing, you might want to override newDocument: or applicationOpenUntitledFile: or otherwise stop the user from invoking it via the File->New menu.

However, the answer above, using the delegate method applicationShouldOpenUntitledFile: will handle the common situations where you'd need that behavior.