# applicationShouldOpenUntitledFile returns NO, but app still opens blank documents

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos, nsdocument

I'm not clear on how to **stop** a document-based application from displaying an empty document at startup.

In a previous question that I posted, someone said, "Are you sure the window delegate is being set correctly and isn't `nil`?"

Can someone elaborate? It appears the Window object in the MyDocument nib is wired by default to File's Owner/Delegate. What else do I need to do? As it stands it's not working.

This method is in MyDocument.m in the project structure. Do I need additional code?

```
- (BOOL)applicationShouldOpenUntitledFile:(NSApplication *)sender  
{
    return NO;
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I create a document-based application that cannot create a new document?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1734229/how-can-i-create-a-document-based-application-that-cannot-create-a-new-document)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It should be in the Application delegate, not the document class, as it says in the [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSApplicationDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html) for the method.